# Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object in JavaFX

Tags: eclipse, javafx, buildpath

I'm following [this JavaFX tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/javafx-with-eclipse) in Eclipse, but when I try building my project, I receive an error:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project  JavaFXProject       Unknown Java Problem

I have tried to fix the build path, but it's not working. Here's a list of the configuration contents installed in Eclipse:

[image: Configuration contents]

And here is the external JAR file already added to the library:

[image: External JAR]

[Just found that the problem is that libraries are missing from the JAR file. See the screenshot below. What could be the solution now?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJhts.png)

Comment: Hey @Yerfdog, can you provide some details about how you've set up your project? Are you following a tutorial?

Comment: Sure, I followed the tutorial from this link https://www.javatpoint.com/javafx-with-eclipse

Comment: Thanks! So, what libraries have you added to your build path under Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries? Share a screenshot if you can.

Comment: See the screenshot from my original post. I cannot add it here on comment

Comment: Just edited your question to include the extra info. I'm pretty rusty with Java development, so hopefully somebody else can help you :)

Comment: Your second screenshot (_Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_) shows that below _Modulepath_ `JRE System Library [JavaSE-21]` is missing. Did you remove it? You can re-add it via the _Add Library..._ button. Make also sure that in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_ you have configured a Java 21 JDK.

Comment: Hello @howgler, I have now fixed the issue of missing JREs. Description Resource Path Location Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. However, the issue has not been resolved. The text in quote is the message I get when checking the error: "Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project JavaFXProject  Unknown Java Problem."

Comment: That tutorial references Java 8, which (from Oracle) included JavaFX.  Modern Java and JavaFX versions are separate.  You should follow the [official documentation at openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) rather than an obsolete tutorial.